# Objective-c UIWebView disable back and forward gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an WebView based app and I really need to disable back/forward gestures inside an uiwebview.
Anyone knows how to do that? I'm being crazy now.

Comment: AFAIK, the back and forward gestures don't work on the UIWebview

Answer (score 0):

Implement the web view delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

and return NO from the method for `UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward` navigation types

Comment: I tried this with no success if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward) {
        return NO;
    }

Comment: was that method being called?

Comment: are you adding any gestures yourself?

Comment: sorry, i can't be much help then. I ran a quick test with a plain web view and there weren't any gestures that I could see (iOS 7, iPhone)